# What is the part without the radical called?

Tags: characters, radicals

For example, these characters have different radicals:

> ### 根 跟 恨 狠

But the part of the characters minus the radical is the same.

Does that part (艮 in this case) have a name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification), this part is defined as "phonetic". I am not familiar with these jargons in English, but I thinks this one is acceptable.

In your case,"艮"(gèn or gěn) is really a character.

**Edit: Add Chinese names for this part**

We call these characters “形声字”(in modern Chinese, many characters can be classified into this type). 形 means "form", referring to the radical, 声 means "sound", so I think "phonetic" is acceptable to call that part.

In Chinese, we call the "radical" 形旁 and the "phonetic" 声旁. Here, 旁(pang2) means a part.

Comment: *"In your case,"艮"(gèn or gěn) is really a character."* Yes, but that wasn't I was asking ;)

Comment: I said, you can call such a part "phonetic"

Comment: Does it have a Chinese name?

Comment: we call these characters “形声字”, 形 means "form", referring to the radical, 声 means "sound", so I think "phonetic" is acceptable to call that part.

Comment: @NullUserException. In Chinese, we call the "radical" 形旁 and "phonetic" 声旁. here， 旁(pang 2) means a part.

Comment: Oh great. You might want to add that to your answer :)

Comment: @NullUserException That's good suggestion. I just edited.

Answer (score 1):

[Victor Mair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_H._Mair), the well known sinologist (and occasionally outspoken advocate of pinyin) [consistently](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3699) [uses](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=3750) the word [*phonophore*](http://pinyin.info/readings/zyg/phonophores.html) to describe the phonetic part of the character.

If you start saying *"phonophore"* too, then there will be upwards of two people using the term. :-)